# Spring cloud - Input vs Output

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

[From this example:](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream-rabbit/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/cloud/stream/rabbit/MultipleOutputsServiceApplication.java)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)
public class MultipleOutputsServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultipleOutputsServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyProcessor processor;

    @StreamListener(MyProcessor.INPUT)
    public void routeValues(Integer val) {
        if (val < 10) {
            processor.anOutput()
                .send(message(val));
        } else {
            processor.anotherOutput()
                .send(message(val));
        }
    }

    private static final <T> Message<T> message(T val) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(val)
            .build();
    }
}
```

MyProcessor interface:

```
public interface MyProcessor {
    String INPUT = "myInput";

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel myInput();

    @Output("myOutput")
    MessageChannel anOutput();

    @Output
    MessageChannel anotherOutput();
}
```

**My question:**

Why the method `routeValues` in `MultipleOutputsServiceApplication` class is annotated with `MyProcessor.INPUT` instead of MyProcessor.myOutput (after adding this member to `MyProcessor` interface) ?

[From the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#__code_source_code_code_sink_code_and_code_processor_code), `INPUT` is for getting data and `OUTPUT` is for sending data. Why the example does the opposite and if I reverse it, nothing is working?

Answer (score 1):

That method looks correct to me. It doesn't have to be annotated with `@Output` as your method doesn't have a return type and you are programmatically sending the output to arbitrary destinations (through two different output bindings) in the method. So you need to make sure that your outputs are bound properly as your program properly does through `@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)`. You need the `@StreamListener(MyProcessor.INPUT)` on the method as `MyProcessor.INPUT` is the binding where StreamListener is listening from. Once you get data through that input, your code then programmatically takes over sending the data downstream. With that said, there are multiple ways to address these types of use cases. You can alternatively doing this too.

```
    @StreamListener
                public void routeValues(@Input("input")SubscribableChannel input, 
    @Output("mOutput") MessageChannel myOutput, 
    @Output("output")MessageChannel output {

        input.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

        int val = (int) message.getPayload();

        if (val < 10) {
            myOutput.send(message(val));
        } 
        else {
            output.send(message(val));
       }
     }
}
```